# onchange function is not working correctly for dropdown when we have 2 or more rows in form in angular 14

Tags: php, typescript, angular14

we are having dropdowns for country state and city with add more row , in second row when we change country 1st row state and city value is also getting changed here we are appending state based on country change and appending city based on state change how can we overcome this issue in angular 14

onchange function for city:

```
 getcity(event,i){
      const icolumn: iColumnName = {
        DynamicTableName:event
      };
      this.FormService.GetColoumnNames(icolumn).subscribe((details)=>{
        this.columnarray = details;
        this.columnval = this.columnarray.data;
      }) 
    }
```

we are trying append values based on index value as we are new to angular we are not getting how to append if any suggestion it mean's ah lot

thanks in advance

Comment: Please show your code, we can't see what's going on without it

Comment: getcity(event,i){
      const icolumn: iColumnName = {
        DynamicTableName:event
      };
      this.FormService.GetColoumnNames(icolumn).subscribe((details)=>{
        this.columnarray = details;
        this.columnval = this.columnarray.data;
      }) 
    }

Comment: onchange function for city

Comment: Code in comments are unreadable. Please [edit] your question and add the code there. Make sure to read [ask] and how to create a [mcve]